# Why are newly asked bad questions marked as favorite by someone?

Tags: support

I have noticed several times on Stack Overflow that newly asked questions are instantly marked as favorite by one person. I have also noticed that it does not always happen, but it seems to happen when the question is of very low quality. At first I thought I was making a big deal out of a coincidence, but I have noticed it too many times to disregard it.

My guess would be that it is Community (background process) that does this, but it is merely a guess. Curiosity demands answers: What is going on?

Comment: Perhaps it was the users themselves?

Comment: I suppose this does raise a question:  what value does favoriting a question have within the first 15 minutes of it being created?

Comment: ...as I favorite *this* question \*giggle\*

Comment: I often do this.  I keep many terrible questions favourited so that I can quickly link them into the recurring 'SO is full of hostile, nazi mobs who downvote for no reason' meta posts.

Comment: The latest example would be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286737/how-to-make-social-network-using-java) question. Is it possible for moderators to see who has marked it as a favorite? I hunger for the answer!

Comment: @Makoto Does marking as favorite bump the question in the activity tab? If not, what value does it have even after 15 minutes?

Comment: @Gendarme:  It gives an individual the ability to return back to it at their leisure, even if the question is deleted (and they have > 10K rep to see it).  Nothing else happens outside of that.  I'm going to see if I can put together a query to determine when a question scoring zero or lower is first favorited and build some data around that.

Comment: The Community user [does not favorite questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites).

Comment: @Gendarme that is indeed truly horrible, but I was not the one to star it.

Comment: If it turns out that most people are just using the Favorite feature as a bookmarking method, would it not be better to just rename it to Bookmark?

Comment: @m69 You do realize that many consider the two synonymous.  IE, for example, doesn't have "bookmarks", it has "favorites".

Comment: @Servy Yes, I know. I just think that calling it Favorites suggests appreciation for the question, whereas Bookmarks only suggests you want to visit it again for whatever reason.

Comment: @m69 And what harm comes from such a false assumption, even if .01% of users do in fact make that false assumption?

Comment: I sometimes favorite questions that are amusingly bad, because I find them amusing.

Comment: @Servy Nothing too serious. Just that new users may be confused about what it really indicates. If people are really bookmarking bad questions to check again later whether they've been improved, the favoriting may give the asker the false impression that their question is good because it's "popular".

Comment: Sometimes I favorite a post when I don't know how to handle it. I'll come back later and see how the veterans dealt with the question. I gain a lot of insight this way.

Comment: There's a query on SEDE which will tell you who favorited a particular question: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/244345/who-favorited-this-post

Comment: The favorite button can be clicked - hence some people click it and some people don't. Does it need to be more difficult than that?

Comment: This question cannot be answered with much confidence. But I guess it is a kind of bookmarking thing. People want to be able to refind these questions... for whatever reason.

Comment: Some people just like to look at train wrecks. It gives them a way to come back later and see what idiocy has developed. At least that's why I do it sometimes.

Comment: And this is the reason why we need a "watch" feature.  You might want to watch a question not favorite it - in fact its not a favorite at all.  I dont know how many arguments I had with @JeffAtwood to fix this back in the days and he was adamant about keeping just "Favorites".

Comment: Sometimes the question is lousy, but one of its _answers_ is excellent, and I know I'll be referring to that answer again in the future.  Since I can't star answers on Stack Overflow, I have to star the question... and later wonder why I did that.

Comment: This was newly asked and already has a bunch of favorites ;-)

Comment: Maybe the hovertext could be changed to something like "Click to bookmark this question; this action doesn't imply you like the question".

Comment: I sometimes _bookmark_ (to not use "favorite") new questions because I'm curious about the topic or specific question without caring about the question's qualitiy. For example I'd like to know an answer to [this (low quality) question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37317099/5528593), but have no immediate need for that. So the bookmark was just out of curiosity without looking at quality issues at all.

Comment: I usually mark questions as favourite when I want to come back later for an edit or for flagging them. I favourite them when I'm mostly on my phone, so that I can log back in from the desktop to do what I wanted to, since I find the desktop version to be far more comfortable to work with.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Agreed. Plenty of downvoted questions have high-quality answers. Just star a question, upvote one of its answers and later check to see which answer you upvoted.

Answer (score 87):

It is probably either the OP or a user who wants to come back and moderate.

If it is the OP, then more than likely they do not understand they will get updates when the post is updated with comments, questions, edits, etc. and think favoriting the post will help them either find it later or keep up to date.

I have also seen users on meta state that if they are out of close votes or downvotes for the day, and come across a post they want to go back and revisit once the count resets, they will favorite the post to make sure not to forget.

Comment: Yeah, I'll favorite a question that is downvoted usually for not providing enough information, but could be solved if the user provided more info.  Usually, someone else already left a comment saying so, so there's no reason for me to also leave a comment, which means I won't be notified when the OP leaves a comment.  So, I favorite and come back a little later and see if I can answer the question.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate mechanism by which a TODO could be applied to the question, in lieu of providing false hope to the OP in the form of a "favorite"? Asking for a friend ;-)

Comment: @lux renaming Favorited to Bookmarked could take away the false impression of popularity. I always assume that the Favorite score of a question doesn't really mean much, and people are just bookmarking the question to come back to later.

Comment: @m69 In that case, I guess Favorite is still a decent name for it, since our guy Brendan sees the potential of earning some *favorable* reputation by answering that question.

Comment: So does this mean we need another way of flagging a question? Favorite has some implied meaning as if many people favor something it is supposed to have a good value/quality. Probably a bookmark flag is needed?

Comment: Aside from mobile users, browser users can already bookmark pages. Beyond that, people in general use bookmarks for different reasons, just as people use favorites for different reasons. I think that the naming doesn't need to change, and it works as designed. As a company, it seems Stack Overflow is working on large feature deployment as opposed to "gold plating" their existing feature set.

Answer (score 38):

Users can favorite their own questions.  So my guess is that users with a very pressing problem are posting bad questions and favoriting them out of pure hope.

Comment: *pure hope* .. gold

Comment: Do I take this as a refutation of my guess?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no community job to favorite random questions.

Answer (score 24):

Because someone clicked 'favorite'.

Comment: Upvote.  This should be the answer.

Comment: Timothy: I like how you upvote your own answer, perhaps you should 'favorite' it.

Answer (score 6):

For me there are two obvious possibilities:

1. The user asking the question favourites it himself/herself
2. The favourite star is awfully close to the downvote button, and may be clicked by accident:

[image: Buttons close together]

Skim readers/skim voters would sometimes be caught out by this.

Answer (score 6):

"I also want to know how to [make a social network using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286737/how-to-make-social-network-using-java)! I'll just bookmark this question and wait for people to answer."

Comment: Question has been deleted by a moderator. But I get your point. Funny.

Comment: @Gendarme "for reasons of moderation" doesn't imply a moderator was involved. It could have been high rep users casting delete votes, or it could have been [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/216712). The only thing it necessarily means is that the user didn't self-delete.

Answer (score 5):

It is not uncommon for terrible beginner questions to get up votes and be marked as a favourite. My guess is that fellow students, on the same course as the asker, do this. Not quite a voting ring, but correlated activity, in most cases.

Comment: Coworkers are another likely possibility.

Answer (score 5):

Because some people use favourites as bookmarks?

Answer (score 4):

In my case the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293400/injection-or-creating-instance-witn-new/37293808#37293808) had the potential for receive a good answer, so despite others were trying to close it I tried to edit the question hoping the OP would try to improve its request instead of randomly asking questions or just abandoning the idea to get support for his problem. I have marked is as favourite because the topic is rather too interesting for me (so I fav what I like nothing more).

What is a "bad" question? I fear this is primarily opinion based. A "bad" question is a question that comes to attention of people that think it is bad before that question comes to attention to people that think that question is good.

I've seen questions much more worse (in my opinion) even getting in hot network and much better questions being closed anyway in comparison to the one I linked above, seems just it is partially luck-based on the type of audience that read the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to track when you add a question to your favorites.

> When you mark a question as a favorite, every activity will notified
> in profile page.

Regular notifications will be triggered only when some one replies, mentions in the comments etc. But, favorite will give notification for every activity on that question.

If a user want to get the status of a post, without answering, without commenting, then he can use favorite button.

#### for example:

A new change in one of my favorite question :
[image: profile page]

Right click on '16h ago', then I can see what changes happened to that post. It was edited 16 hours back.

I often favorite a question after answering it. Newbies tend to reply in their our questions or commenting somewhere else(So, I won't be notified). But adding a favorites, gives the status of that question.

Comment: Note: the (1) there has nothing to do with the edit, in my experience; it's just a sum of new comments and answers. Many times I've gone to that tab when it said (1) and seen half a dozen questions highlighted with new edits. Even sometimes when there was no number at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, When I checked the activity status in above image, it is clearly an edit by 'j08691'. There are not additional comments added to that question. [Post link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/272544#272544),[edit link of same post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/272544/revisions) for reference.

Comment: If your previous check was before Apr 14 (but after Mar 22), I strongly suspect my comment on the *question* was responsible for the number. The favorites implementation does not bother to link to new comments, however many or few there may be.