# Should we move the favorite button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes, user-interface, bookmarks

I saw a lot of questions with a big negative score and a little favorite score.

In my opinion, some people click on the favorite button in place of the down vote button.

I will try to add every question that I think will match with this case (I didn't note them before) (feel free to comment or [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/340005/edit) it if you find some):

- [Need help for strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255186/need-help-for-strlen)

**Should we move the favorite button?**

Comment: What data do you have to back this up besides your opinion?

Comment: Users are allowed to favorite their own question.

Comment: @Daedalus Well, like it a user interface problem and that is a problem cause by inattention it's hard to prove. That's why I am asking other opinion. I will try to add some "clues".

Comment: @Andy I didn't think about it, that explains some case.

Comment: Related: [Why are newly asked bad questions marked as favorite by someone?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323231)

Comment: Maybe they're favoriting it because they ran out of votes today, but want to make sure they come back tomorrow to give it a downvote!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Favoriting a down voted question might be done because you want to get notified of changes to it, so you can come back to the question in case it improves. I have done this a couple of times as well.

So I do not think the location of the favorite button should be changed. We do not have any means to know, whether the person pressing the favorite button really wanted to down vote the question. The UI is pretty clear and I guess that in most cases you would realize your misclick once you've done it.

Comment: You convinced me, I didn't read [how favorite work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580). I assumed that was just a bookmark but I was wrong. Maybe "favorite" isn't a good name because this behavior look like a "follow" feature.

Comment: It... *is* just a bookmark. @star

Answer (score 3):

I disagree.

The OP of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255186/need-help-for-strlen) you linked us to has [favorited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7323813/kervin-smith?tab=favorites) his own question, which is allowed. This doesn't mean that he wanted to downvote himself and hit the favorite button by mistake.

The current design looks good, and the buttons are already far enough apart. I don't see any reason to reconsider it.